# How connect Usb to laptop without Usb?

Tags: usb, laptop, chipset

My msi gp62 7rd laptop lost all of the Usb ports cause of the chipset problem ! Laptop is not able to repair or chipset replacement...
How can i connect usb device like a mouse ?
I have sata port , laptop pci (for wifi) and network lan

Comment: A laptop is not like a desktop to which you could add e.g. an add-on PCIe USB card.

Comment: See if you have Bluetooth as part of wireless and you can connect a Bluetooth mouse. If you can, you would have to start the laptop with the keyboard and wait for bluetooth to load

Comment: Bluetooth drive is disabled too . I search for a way to make just 1 usb drive to connect a usb Bluetooth or usb hub to it

Comment: Well, then buy a second hand replacement

Comment: Connect to  a device, such as Raspberry Pi or another PC, that has USB ports via the RJ45 Ethernet jack. Finding or writing the code to link them might not be trivial. Seems a shame to leave a high-end laptop such as yours unrepaired, though.

Comment: Unfortunately msi company said problem is from chipset and replacement is not avaible

Answer (score 0):

You didnt mention the make or model of your laptop, so I can only give a generic answer.

If your laptop has either a PCMCIA port or a Express Card slot, you could add USB that way.

If your laptop supports a dock (non-USB based, obviously), you might be able to add USB through the dock.

As John mentioned in the comments, Bluetooth would be an option to add a mouse, keyboard, or other peripherals.  Almost every modern laptop supports Bluetooth.

Comment: Thank u for answering ,Model is msi gp627rd

Comment: Bluetooth device (intel combo) disabled too

Comment: What about  getting a dock as was suggested?

Comment: There is no dock for this model . ☹️

Comment: Modern laptops don't have PCMCIA or Express Card. The dock isn't a solution either (and it hasn't that option anyway) because USB in those docks is via an hub, it depends on the motherboard's controller as well.

Comment: A comment burried in a teardown of the laptop at https://www.insidemylaptop.com/full-disassembly-guide-for-msi-ge62-gp62-pe60/ says "USB ports on the right side are soldered to the motherboard.
One USB port on the left side, by the card media reader, also soldered but it’s located on I/O board. You can replace the board to get the USB port working.
Otherwise, you have to de-solder the damaged USB and solder a new one in."

Comment: Problem is from chipset , sockets and parts are completely ok .

Comment: Yeah, **its a long shot** - but see https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004980851744.html - If that IO board includes a USB driver IC (it might - I can't see it closely enough - it may be enough to get the 1 port wporking.   Does your SD port work?

Comment: Sd c-r and every devive which was on usb (host controller) are disabled ...

Comment: I search for a way to convert cd wr sata port or networklan port to usb

Comment: There's no way to do that. Your options are repair or replace, end of story.

Comment: I don't think you will find a decent, polished solution, and its likely not worth the effort.  https://www.flexihub.com/usb-over-ip-raspberry-pi/ may be a partial solution to allow you to use a Pi as a virtual ethernet to USB interface.